# Vector of pointers: some clarification needed

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have read a lot about vector of pointers on this forum but have trouble grasping the idea of deleting the pointers stored in the vector. Following is my query:

Suppose I dynamically create an array of objects

```
CPoint* dynamic_array;
dynamic_array = new CPoint[30714];
```

I now have to use these values in object of another class through vector of pointers

```
vector<CPoint*> vector_of_pointers;
```

I will then divide the elements of `dynamic_array` into objects of another class using the following

```
Class B{
    vector<CPoint*> vector_of_pointers;
public:
    void function(CPoint* a){
        if (some condition){
            vector_of_pointers.push_back(a);
        }
};
```

Where `a` will always be a pointer to object from `dynamic_array`

I then plan to delete the originally created dynamic_array, after the need for its objects is over.

```
delete[] dynamic_array;
```

Is deleting each pointer in the vector necessary even after doing this? And if it is necessary can I do it in the destructor for `Class B`?

Sorry if this is a simple or silly question but I am newbie in c++ and using a container is necessary for my application.

Comment: You most likely just want a `std::vector<CPoint>`. If you *need* a pointer, use a smart pointer.

Comment: It is not necessary to delete the elements of the vector. In fact, it would be an error. After the call to `delete`[]`, you can't dereference the elements.

Comment: I believe the problem here concerns memory ownership. As soon as you delete the dynamic_array, the pointers in your vector will point to invalid places in memory. Consistently using vectors might help. You might want to look at boost::ptr_vector or boost::shared_ptr

Answer (score 4):

To answer your original question: No, you don't need to delete individual `CPoint` objects (in fact you can't).

But I do believe that you'd be better off using `vector<CPoint>` to store the actual point, rather than a pointer to it.

Answer (score 3):

The pointers that you store in your `vector<CPoint*>` point to objects that you already `deleted` with your `delete[] dynamic_array` instruction, so you don't have to, and also should not, add `delete` instructions on the individual pointers stored in your vector.

Answer (score 0):

> Is deleting each pointer in the vector necessary even after doing this? And if it is necessary can I do it in the destructor for Class B?

The answer is no and in fact you can't.

Whether or not it is better to just use `std::vector` I think it depends on your needs but I can confirm that using `new[]` is a lot faster than creating each object separatelly. Some times:

```
class CPoint {
public:
    float x; float y;
}

const int N = 1e6;
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    new CPoint();
}
// 122 ms

CPoint* points = new CPoint[N];
// 0.00793176 ms

std::vector<CPoint*> vectorPoints(N); // same as above
// 4.48263 ms
```

Using `std::vector<CPoint*>(N)` is also fast but not faster as `new[]`

Answer (score 0):

deleting CPoint objects pointed by pointers in the vector is not necessary and is impossible but the pointers in the vector must be removed from the vector.

you must clear the vector because it holds at least 4*number_of_elements(8*number_of_elements in x64 systems) of useless pointers.